# SimpleXML Skipping Attributes

Tags: php, simplexml, xmlreader

**Test XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Transfer>
    <ABR recordLastUpdatedDate="20180329" replaced="N">
        <ABN status="ACT" ABNStatusFromDate="20000214">80007321682</ABN>
        <EntityType>
            <EntityTypeInd>PUB</EntityTypeInd>
            <EntityTypeText>Australian Public Company</EntityTypeText>
        </EntityType>
        <MainEntity>
            <NonIndividualName type="MN">
                <NonIndividualNameText>BLACK CABS COMBINED PTY LTD</NonIndividualNameText>
            </NonIndividualName>
            <BusinessAddress>
                <AddressDetails>
                    <State>VIC</State>
                    <Postcode>3166</Postcode>
                </AddressDetails>
            </BusinessAddress>
        </MainEntity>
    </ABR>
</Transfer>
```

**PHP Script:**

```
$f='test.xml';
$reader=new XMLReader();
$reader->open($f);
while($reader->read()){
    if($reader->nodeType==XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name=='ABR'){
        $doc=new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
        $xml=simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($reader->expand(),true));
        print_r($xml);
    }
}
$reader->close();
```

**PHP Output:**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [recordLastUpdatedDate] => 20180329
            [replaced] => N
        )

    [ABN] => 80007321682
    [EntityType] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [EntityTypeInd] => PUB
            [EntityTypeText] => Australian Public Company
        )

    [MainEntity] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [NonIndividualName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => MN
                        )

                    [NonIndividualNameText] => BLACK CABS COMBINED PTY LTD
                )

            [BusinessAddress] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [AddressDetails] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [State] => VIC
                            [Postcode] => 3166
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

**The Problem:**

The attributes for the `ABN` element (`status` and `ABNStatusFromDate`) are not in the output, even though other attributes are.

Please help me understand why those attributes in particular are missing.

*PS - Dummy text so SO doesn't give me warnings about my post being mostly code*

Comment: Note an answer, just a note: `print_r($xml->ABN)` shows them. Also, `print_r($xml)` shows them if you have a child node (eg: `<ABN status="ACT" ABNStatusFromDate="20000214"><node>80007321682</node></ABN>`).

Comment: I've figured it out: `print_r` is a terrible way of outputting XML data. I am now on the right track by just referencing the XML data directly.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: `print_r` is not meant to be used to display a SimpleXML object.

I can access the attribute directly via `$xml->ABN['status']`.